# Catel ModelBase PropertyData deserialization

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, catel

Began to develop a WCF-WPF application.

Data between client and server is encrypted at the message level. 
Implemented a custom authentication and authorization using their own policies based on roles and user name and password.

Faced with a strange error. 
The application works if simple types or types implement [DataContract] transferred between the client and the server.
But, when i try to transfer items containing PropertyData of Catel library. 
Getting an exception
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException:  (DigestVerificationFailedForReference) test failed digest for links \ "# _0 \". "

app.config

```
  <serviceCredentials>
    <serviceCertificate findValue="01" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
      storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber" />
    <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
      customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="TS.PortraitExpertise.AuthWCF.CustomUserNameValidator, TS.PortraitExpertise.AuthWCF" />
  </serviceCredentials>
```

model excample

```
    [Serializable]
    public  class TestModel : ModelBase
    {
        public TestModel()
        {
        }

        protected TestModel(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
            : base(info, context) { }


        /// <summary>
        /// Unique key.
        /// </summary>
        public int Id
        {
            get { return GetValue<int>(IdProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IdProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Register the Id property so it is known in the class.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly PropertyData IdProperty = RegisterProperty("Id", typeof(int));
    }
```

If you disable encryption at the message level, the data is transmitted normally. If you just serialize an object, and then deserialized, the operation is completed normally. 
Problem if played between serialization and deserialization models Katel added encryption. 
How can I solve the problem does not waive models Catel?

Comment: If you create an official ticket at the issue tracker, I will look into it: http://www.catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker/

Comment: Thank you very much for helping create a issue CTL-308

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For data transfer between client and server use ssl. 
Issue state  https://catelproject.atlassian.net/browse/CTL-308